# SSRS column and line chart?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hello I have a simple dataset in SQL that counts meter readings... There are meter readings every day and I would like to SUM the count, display that in a column chart at a daily interval.  What I would also like to do is display a cumulative count as a line so 4 orders Monday, 3 orders Tuesday, 5 orders Wednesday 4+3+5 etc. Apparently there is a running total property I read somewhere in SSRS?  Does anyone know how to do this? I'm stumped! I currently have a SUM of count as my total value with category group of date read but it does not seem to be displaying properly.  Instead of saying 5 orders on tuesday, it is just showing 1,1,1,1,1 etc...

```
SELECT     COUNT(readingId), dateRead
FROM         Readings
WHERE     (dateRead BETWEEN @StarDate AND @EndDate) AND (webcontactid IS NOT NULL) AND (meter = 1)
GROUP BY Readings.dateRead
```

[image: as you can see the 19 March is missing as I have found that there is no data... Is there any way I can get it to display a 0 or something to show there is nothing?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a bar chart, put dt as Category group, added a fake Series group called g1 (Group by "A"), and used two data fields, one with the expression

```
=Sum(Fields!NReadings.Value)
```

and one with the expression

```
=RunningValue(Fields!NReadings.Value, Sum, "g1")
```

and set this to appear as a line.

I got this on SSRS 2005, but I hope it helps for 2008. If anyone has a way to do this without creating a fake Series, then please let me know.

[image]

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for the 'runningvalue' function... The only issue I have now is that for some reason one of the days on my x axis is not displaying... I'll update my original post to try and include a pic...

Comment: as you can see the 19 March is missing as I have found that there is no data... Is there any way I can get it to display a 0 or something to show there is nothing?

Comment: I've created a custom expression which I thought would work by forcing a non existing value to 0 but it doesn't seem to be doing anything?  =IIf(Sum(Fields!TotalReadings.Value) Is Nothing, 0, (Sum(Fields!TotalReadings.Value)))

Comment: @jeff Try setting the `Scalar axis` property for the X axis to see if that will laave spaces for 0 values.

Comment: Yes that works! I can see the date now but it is just blank, how can I get it to display 0?